# Microsoft Redis Session State Provider on AWS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I'm building a web farm environment for an ecommerce package. The package runs on .NET + AWS.

The package gives the ability to store session state in Redis Cache. The problem is that when I use Amazon Redis (v 2.82 I think) I get connectivity exceptions when trying to use the cache. No such issues on Azure. 
the only difference that I see between the configs is that azure requires password whereas AWS does not.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at StackExchange.Redis.ServerEndPoint.get_LastException()
at StackExchange.Redis.ExceptionFactory.GetServerSnapshotInnerExceptions(ServerEndPoint[] serverSnapshot)
at StackExchange.Redis.ExceptionFactory.NoConnectionAvailable(Boolean includeDetail, RedisCommand command, Message message, ServerEndPoint server, ServerEndPoint[] serverSnapshot)
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags)
at Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Eval>b__3()
at Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryForScriptNotFound(Func`1 redisOperation)
at Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryLogic(Func`1 redisOperation)
at Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.Eval(String script, String[] keyArgs, Object[] valueArgs)
at Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.Set(ISessionStateItemCollection data, Int32 sessionTimeout)
at Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)
```

Comment: Can we see the code that this exception is referencing?

Comment: This is nopCommerce.com package. I would have to go to the source to find out. The point is that the site crashes on every session state usage as if AWS Redis was refusing connection. The package has no issue using AWS redis while caching ui data. Only the Microsoft.Web.Redis provider has issues on AWS.

Comment: In my cases using ASP.NET 4.7.1 and using this package works fine on redis local. But doesnt allow to connect Aws Elastic cache..